# Docker Laravel 11 issue: How to switch Laravel versions

Tags: laravel, docker, composer-php, laravel-10, laravel-11

I am currently learning Laravel by watching [this course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wn3IPX_ax-0&list=WL&index=8&t=11429s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org). I attempted to install Laravel 10 using the following command:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

However, this command installs Laravel 11 instead. I specifically need Laravel 10 because the dependency [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) does not support Laravel 11. How can I install Laravel 10?

Comment: What else did you try to resolve your problem? How is this problem related to Docker or Composer?

Answer (score 0):

By using command which is in the doc:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

This will download the latest laravel version(11). To install laravel 10, use `composer`, then, if you are using sail, download the package, and run:

```
php artisan sail:install
```

As doc said.
I reviewed the package to make something like category and subcategory as I understood. If so, this can easily be done using laravel, no need for external package. You can read articles about that to understand the point.

Comment: when using curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" 
it download some package i don't know all of them
but he used mailpit in the video

Comment: it pulls 6 images from docker you can see them in docker-compse.yml file but if you download laravel using composer then sail package when run php artisan sail:install you can choose wich images and container do you want to build